# How do I force a Vue component to use updated local storage

Tags: vue.js

In my current project on the homepage, I have an image, that is controlled by a variable that is set and retrieved from local storage.  In a separate selection component two things happen when the user makes a selection:

1. the local storage variable is updated
2. the user is redirected back to the home page `` this.$router.push(`/home`); ``

The image however does not update when the user is redirected back.

For example:
The user starts out with image A.  They then select image B from the selection component.  Upon redirection back to the home page local storage is showing image B, however, the home page is still showing image A.  Now if I refresh or click to another component and then back to the home page it is then updated to image B.

My first easiest thought was to force a refresh upon the redirect back to the home page.  For this I have seen the usage of `:key=''`, however, I have not seen an example of that working with a `router.push`.

I am using the quasar framework, and a `<q-btn/>` when I tried wrapping it with a `<route-viewer/>` did not work for me either.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you expect localStorage to be reactive when it's not by itself. If you bind your localStorage variable to the component data, you would still need to manually update it when you update it in localStorage. I would recommend using a store for your issue. so when you update you localStorage value, you will sync the value with the localStorage and vue store. Then you could use the store value in the component, which will be reactive, and set the initial value in the store from localStorage.

Comment: you can use event bus for listening any updates through components